# How to set an array in session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am little bit struggling in setting array in session.

Here is my code:-

**Controller:**

```
function taketest(){
    $this->load->model('', '');
    $questions_for_test = $this->session->userdata('questions_for_test');
    $difficulty_level = $this->session->userdata('difficulty_level');
    $question_id = $this->session->userdata('question_id');
    if($question_id==""){
        $question_id = $this->myjcat->returnRandomQuestion($questions_for_test,$difficulty_level);
        $this->session->set_userdata('question_id',$question_id);
    }
    $question_details = $this->myjcat->getQuestion($question_id);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function returnRandomQuestion($questions_for_test, $difficulty_level){
    $question_id = array_rand($questions_for_test[$difficulty_level], 1);
    $used_question=array();
    $used_questions=$questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id];
    $this->session->set_userdata('used_questions',$used_questions);
    return $questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id];
}
```

But when I call:

```
$used_questions = $this->session->userdata('used_questions');
```

in controller
in the controller it will not return me an array.It gives me last value stored in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be misreading things, but it looks like you are only storing one value.

```
// this code:
$used_questions=$questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id];
$this->session->set_userdata('used_questions',$used_questions);

// is the same as this code
$this->session->set_userdata('used_questions',$questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id]);
```

You're probably looking for this:

```
// fetch the stored copy first.
$used_questions = $this->session->userdata('used_questions');
if(!is_array($used_questions)) $used_questions = array();
// note the []
$used_questions[] = $questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id];
$this->session->set_userdata('used_questions',$used_questions);
```

Comment: Yes it is same.But every time when this function has been called,one question has been used.so i need to make an array so that used questions cant be repeat again.

Answer (score 2):

You can set array values in session data like this :-

```
$this->session->set_userdata('used_questions', json_encode($used_questions));
```

And retrieve the data as :-

```
json_decode($this->session->userdata('used_questions'));
```

If you want the retrieved array data as associative array :-

```
json_decode($this->session->userdata('used_questions'), true);
```

Hope it hepls you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$used_questions` is storing the value stored in `$questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id]` and not the array.

So do this `$this->session->set_userdata('used_questions',$questions_for_test);`

Comment: This cant resolve my problem.As $questions_for_test is the array of total number of questions.But i need to make an array of used questions.

Comment: So, do this: 
$used_questions = $this->session->userdata('used_questions');
$used_questions[$difficulty_level][$question_id] = $questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id];
    $this->session->set_userdata('used_questions',$used_questions);

This will let you recover the questions stored by de array in the session, and then add them the new question. Finally with set_userdata you store the "new array"(wich contains the old values and the new one) in the session rewriting the old array stored with the key 'used_questions'

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data you pass to the $used_questions is a value.

You might want to do something like this:

```
array_push($used_questions, $questions_for_test[$difficulty_level][$question_id]);
```

*appending / adding a new value to an array